#  Why can't I select the folder to send to the cloud for sync?

Tags: sync, directory, ubuntu-one-windows

A message says I am limited to syncing folders in c:\My Documents\ .

Do I understand this correctly?
If so, it looks like a stupid design decision to me.

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu One?

Comment: In Ubuntu, one can only sync folders - with Ubuntu One - inside the home directory. I guess that would be the same with Windows, you can probably sync with folders only from inside of your My Documents directory.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One [FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/can-i-synchronize-a-folder-outside-my-home-folder-117/) makes it clear that you can select only those folders in your Home directory to synchronize.

> No, currently you can only select to synchronize folders inside your home directory on both Windows and Ubuntu.

You can *probably* try symlinking/[creating a junction in Windows](https://superuser.com/a/337986/4377) to try put content from outside folders into your Ubuntu One folder and try syncing it<sup>**+**</sup>.

<sup>**+**</sup>note that I haven't yet tried this.

Comment: * But I have found it to work in a VM